# Tkinter Widget Placement

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create a desktop file converter application for myself using tkinter.  It so far has a drag and drop area, and a button you can press to just select the file from the file explorer.  However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly position the widgets so they sit on top of each other.  I want it so the drag and drop box is off the the left side of the screen, and in the middle of the box I want a text widget that says, "Drag and drop file, or select them", with a button widget below it that allows them to select from the file manager if they please.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
from TkinterDnD2 import DND_FILES, TkinterDnD
from conversion import *

#global variables
path_to_file = " "
file_type = " "
compatable_converstion = []

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("File Converter")
        self.master.minsize(1000,600)
        self.master.maxsize(1200,800)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        #Drag and drop files area
        self.drop_box = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, background="#99ff99")
        self.drop_box.pack(ipadx=170)
        self.drop_box.pack(ipady=120)
        self.drop_box.pack(side="left")
        self.drop_box.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
        self.drop_box.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", open_dropped_file)
        #Select file button
        self.select_file = tk.Button(self)
        self.select_file["text"] = "Select File"
        self.select_file["command"] = self.open_selected_file
        self.select_file.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")
        #Instructional Text
        sentence = "Drag and drop or select your file"
        self.instructions = tk.Text(root)
        self.instructions.insert(tk.END, sentence)
        self.instructions.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")

    def open_selected_file(self):
        path_to_file = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select A File", filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
        temp_str = " "
        for chars in reversed(path_to_file):
            if(chars == '.'):
                break
            temp_str += chars
        file_type = temp_str[::-1]
        compatable_converstion = retrieve_compatable_conversions(file_type)

def main():
    global root
    root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Just in case my explanation of how I want it laid out sucks, here is a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the widgets `self.drop_box` and `self.instructions` on the root window. They should be created on `self`.

The `place()` geometry manager does not reserve space in a widget, so you will have to make the widget(`self`) as big as necessary with `expand=True, fill='both'`. I would advise using the `grid()` geometry manager for any design which is not really simple.

The widgets will be stacked in the order they are placed, which means that the Button will be hidden beneath the Text widget. Just change the order in which they are placed.

As for using `ipadx` and `ipady` in the `pack()` function, have a look at [Why does the 'ipady' option in the tkinter.grid() method only add space below a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264614/why-does-the-ipady-option-in-the-tkinter-grid-method-only-add-space-below-a)

Also; you don't need to make root a global variable because the application knows it as `self.master`.

Here is an example, not of the whole program but the parts I have mentioned:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("File Converter")
        self.master.minsize(1000,600)
        self.master.maxsize(1200,800)
        self.pack(expand=True, fill='both') # Fill entire root window
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        #Drag and drop files area
        self.drop_box = tk.Listbox(self, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, background="#99ff99")
        self.drop_box.pack(side="left", ipadx=170, ipady=120)
        self.drop_box.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
        self.drop_box.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", open_dropped_file)
        #Instructional Text
        sentence = "Drag and drop or select your file"
        self.instructions = tk.Text(self)
        self.instructions.insert(tk.END, sentence)
        self.instructions.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")
        #Select file button
        self.select_file = tk.Button(self, text="Select File",
                                     command=self.open_selected_file)
        self.select_file.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")
```

This should let you work out most of your problems.